# cufon glyphs support

Tags: javascript, font-face, cufon, glyph

I have a problem with cufon and a few Turkish glyphs. This is the context:

I used the @font-face property to embed the custom font (Delicious-Roman) on a website. The client didn't like the fact that the font was the last one to load on each page (common issue with font-face) so I switched to cufon. When I was using font-face all the characters worked as they should, but when I used cufon a few glyphs stopped working (they simply don't show up on the page). I opened up Photoshop to test the font and indeed it doesn't have those Turkish characters (ğĞİşŞ).

1. Why the font-face property managed to show all the characters even if the font didn't have them?
2. How can I add those Turkish characters (ğĞİşŞ) to cufon?

I tried the "...and also these single characters" option on the cufon website but it didn't worked. I simply inserted the characters - ğĞİşŞ - in that text field. Is that correct?

If there is no way to add these glyphs to cufon, what is the easiest way to add them directly in the font I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found was to simply include the missing characters into the font and the re-use cufon. For this task I used the [Glyph App](http://glyphsapp.com) - Demo version works perfectly for 30 days and you can export fonts without restriction.